# How to Dynamically create Spring bean and Set Annotations on the newly created bean

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

Am trying to to dynamically create Spring bean and Set Annotations on the newly created bean to unit test the below piece of code

```
class BeanMetadata 
{
    int id;
    String type;
    String beanName;
    Date createdAt;
    Date createdBy;
}
```

This method gets the bean name from BeanMetadata and searches in the applicationCOntext for the given bean and checks if the bean has `@OperationExecutePermission` or `@AdministerPermission` annotations present on the bean.

So am trying to to dynamically create Spring bean and Set these annotations on the newly created

```
void addCommandPermissions(BeanMetadata command) {
    if (applicationContext.containsBean(command.getBeanName())) {
            Object bean = applicationContext.getBean(command.getBeanName());
            Class<?> beanClass = bean.getClass();
            if (beanClass.isAnnotationPresent(AdministerPermission.class)) {
                overrideAdminPermission =   beanClass.getAnnotation(AdministerPermission.class).name();
            }
            if (beanClass.isAnnotationPresent(OperationExecutePermission.class)) {
                overrideExecPermission =    beanClass.getAnnotation(OperationExecutePermission.class).name();
            }
        }
```

I am trying to achieve if `(beanClass.isAnnotationPresent(AdministerPermission.class))` must be true or  if `(beanClass.isAnnotationPresent(OperationExecutePermission.class))` must be true for the newly created bean.

Comment: Please clarify. What do you mean by set annotations?

Comment: For the newly created bean beanClass.isAnnotationPresent(AdministerPermission.class) has to be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add annotations to anything at runtime.

The best you can do here is create a class that has the annotations. You can then test your code with classes that have the annotations and classes that don't.

Comment: If I create a class inside my test case can i register it with the applicationContext at runtime?

Comment: @RanPaul You can have an applicationContext just for test environments.

Comment: our environment is quite a bit different, test suite is part of our application and i can not use test applicationContext

Comment: @RanPaul Then you will have to declare that bean as part of the applicationContext and simply not use it in production.